# Bounties on meta questions

Tags: feature-request, bounty, meta

I asked a question here on meta yesterday and I'd really like to have an answer, so I thought about putting a bounty on it in the next days (as it has low views and more views / votes would help).

But then I realized that there is no "add bounty" button. So I searched, but couldn't find a post explaining why that is.

So, I'm requesting the ability to put bounties on question on meta using my main-site rep and having it awarded the main-site rep of the answerer.

Also sometimes I see long and beautiful answers here on meta and would have liked to give the authors some more "reward" than an up vote.

PS: I didn't link the question here as I would want to have that feature anyway.

Comment: Meta has no influence on the rep of the participating users, which should stay that way. You don't want a person who has 10k rep because he collects meta points all day, rep should indicate actual expertise.

Comment: @l4mpi Yes, I would want that.

Comment: @l4mpi Also, gaining 10k rep through meta-bounties would take an aweful lot of work, don't you think? I'm not wanting rep for up/downvotes or accepted answers, just for bounties.

Comment: Still, you would make reputation depend on something else than _actual expertise in the topics of the site_, which is simply not what reputation is about.

Comment: @l4mpi While I can't think of any real-world situation where that would make any difference, you are technically correct.

Comment: The irony is that I'd not like to put a bounty on this question because it "hasn't received enough attention."

Comment: The meta site should have its own points, just like any distinct SO site.  When setting a bounty on a meta question, you should be able to use your points from the associated regular site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no bounties on child metas because there is no reputation on child metas.

All reputation is taken from the parent site. You will note that upvotes, downvotes, accepts and suggested edits don't give reputation on a child meta either.

Changing the bounty system to make reputation meaningful on a child meta goes against all that.

Comment: I still would want to have no rep influence on upvote / accept etc. Just for bounties.

Comment: Why should they behave differently to everything else?

Comment: Because an upvote costs me nothing. A bounty is something that I "pay for" which makes them quite different. - Related: If not with bounties, how am I supposed to increase eyeballs on my meta-question?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer you're not supposed to. You post a good question or you don't; there's no meta question that's so utterly important that you absolutely need to offer your own rep for views and possibly answers. Besides, meta doesn't have many questions, so it's not like your question is buried beneath thousands of others. I guess you're talking about the JasperReports question, which I (and probably most meta regulars) saw yesterday - IMO it's simply not a topic enough people care about to find someone who would write an answer or a comment. And it's certainly not terribly important either.

Comment: @l4mpi Thats why I didn't link it (it really isn't that important). I'd still like to have that feature.

Comment: You still haven't addressed the *actual* question: *How do I get/attract more attention for my questions on Meta?* A question asked during non-peak times might go into oblivion. Editing is one way to "push" it up but that's not always enough.

Comment: @BlueMoon - meta has much, much, much less traffic than Stack Overflow. Things do not drop off the front page all that fast. The people who frequent meta do go through the front page - so this isn't as much of a problem as it is for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Oded so I have a low-views-zero-comments-zero-votes kind of a question here in meta.so on which I would love to get at least some feedback. What should I do? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @eis - edit the post. Add details. That will bump it up to the front page.

Comment: We could still withdraw the meta bounty reputation from the main site...

Answer (score 19):

I for one would quite like to have the choice to spend my rep here.

Perhaps more of a "*spend rep to have my question highlighted*" than "*trade my rep for an answer*".
What I mean is that my rep would be lost to me forever and deducted from my main account but the "bounty" is not awarded to answerers as that appears against people's (or perhaps the network's?) belief that no rep should be gained on meta child sites.

It wouldn't be quite in line with how bounties function the main sites (and would perhaps need an alternative name/term for it) where it is meant to attract answers for questions in return for bonus rep but instead more a method to garner extra attention in exchange for rep would be nice to have as an option. It would show that a user has an interest or above average belief in the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to highlight that you may ask, most of the time, the same questions on **meta.stackoverflow.com** and **meta.stackexchange.com**.

Posting on MSE [***is also absolutely fine***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232)!

And the posts on https://meta.stackexchange.com can be awarded bounties. So if the question is worth it network-wide, share it and bounty it. But note that it won't be using your Stack Overflow reputation, it will be using your specific Meta Stack Exchange reputation, so you need a bit of participation to MSE.