# Help Center text update related to bounties on Meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, bounty, help-center

**Background:**

Today I wanted to award a bounty for a Meta Stack Overflow question, but failed to find the add bounty link.

So, I wondered if bounties worked differently in Meta and decided to check `help` --> `What's Meta?`. Here also I didn't find what I was looking for.

Finally I came to this question ([Bounties on meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265798/bounties-on-meta-questions)) where I found my answer in one of the posts.

**Feature Request:**

I would like to have information about how bounties differ on Meta in the [What's Meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page. Do y'all agree, or is there some other, better suited, place I could have gotten this help.

Please note that this is a feature-request for information about bounties on Meta, and not a request for bounties on Meta.

Comment: No rep on meta, so no bounty. It's very logical and doesn't require to be explicitly mentioned IMO.

Comment: I dont think it is a dupe. This is a feature-request to show **information about how bounties differ on meta in the What's Meta page**. It is not a feature-request to allow bounty on Meta posts.

Comment: @AzizShaikh Exactly! I've updated my post to make this more clear.

Comment: @ljgw I have made some more edits. You may rollback the edits if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fine with the edits!

Comment: To add to the confusion, [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) used to be part of Meta.SO and the entire site had its own rep system... and I want to say its own bounties.