# What's the reason for auto-awarding bounties only on answers coming after the bounty is offered?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Answers already existing at the moment a bounty is offered on a question are not candidate for the *auto-awarding* of the bounty. I wondered what was the underlying rationale behind this choice.

There are a lot of questions on meta about bounties but I didn't find one where this point is discussed or even alluded to. And the help page just states the rule.

I'm *not* claiming this is a bad thing, I'm pretty sure there's a good reason and am eager to understand it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The auto-award feature is basically a form of insurance for answerers.  It **encourages users to answer bountied questions** by guaranteeing that, if they spend the effort to write a good answer (good enough to at least get two upvotes during the bounty period), they'll have a chance of getting at least half of the bounty even if the user who started it drops the ball and fails to actually award the bounty for some reason (e.g. because they don't realize that they need to, or because they just don't visit SO often and miss the deadline).

Making pre-existing answers eligible for the auto-award would not serve this goal, since those answers were not written in response to the bounty.  Furthermore, in some cases it could actually be counterproductive, e.g. if the question already had a highly upvoted (but, in the bounty creator's mind, unsatisfactory) answer.

Of course, the bounty creator can still choose to manually award the bounty to a pre-existing answer, e.g. if that was their intention all along, or if they find none of the new answers satisfactory.  But the primary purpose of bounties is still to invite new good answers, and if that indeed occurs (i.e. a new answer is posted and gets upvoted by multiple users during the bounty period), it *should* take a deliberate choice by the bounty author to snub that new answer and instead award the bounty to some other one.  If they don't, the automatic fallback should certainly not presume to do so.

(It could perhaps be argued that the auto-award should behave differently if the bounty author selects the "one of the existing answers is exemplary" reason when starting the bounty, as that constitutes an explicit declaration of intent to award the bounty to an older answer.  But even then, the system — as currently implemented — doesn't generally know *which* existing answer the bounty was meant for, so the only safe default would be not to auto-award it at all.  Which currently happens anyway, if no new answers with 2+ score have been posted during the bounty period.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis. I can maybe now give an additional information to my original post, that I had let aside not to focus on the specific case, but I've been, as you probably could guess, one of these already-upvoted but "probably unsatisfactory to the OP" answers. And from the point the bounty was put on the question, one new answer popped, was never upvoted (aside from me, only upvoter of the answer), while mine kept being upvoted more. When grace period ended, the count was 5 to 0. And I had a 6th vote and the acceptation tick the day after. There for the underlying story.

Comment: ...and just to defuse potential misunderstandings or assumptions : 1) I'm very happy with the outcome of all this 2) I don't feel like this mechanism should be changed 3) with a better understanding of how bounties work, now I feel like I legitimately would *not* have deserved it. OP hoped for a guru to pop in I guess. Which I'm definitely *not*. :-)

Comment: @RomainValeri: Was the bounty started by the OP? If so, and given that they did end up accepting your answer, it sounds like they just dropped the ball somehow. Maybe they thought your answer was wrong or incomplete or otherwise poor, and it took them so long to realize that it actually was OK that the bounty had expired in the mean time? Or maybe they just forgot about the bounty.

Comment: Yeah, probably so, and moreover the OP is a "serial bounty giver", with arguably a lot of current bounties at different stages, which could lead to what you call "dropping the ball". I've refrained from posting a link to the question... should I?

Comment: @RomainValeri: Up to you, I guess. FWIW, I just looked at your profile on SO, and I'm pretty sure I can tell from your description which answer it was. Anyway, it sounds like you got something like 75 rep out of that bounty out of that bounty, even without actually getting the bounty itself. That's not too shabby. :)

Comment: "Anyway, it sounds like you got something like 75 rep out of that bounty, even without actually getting the bounty itself. That's not too shabby" >>> defused 8 minutes ago ;-) Agreed *before* you stated it. And now I've read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265798/bounties-on-meta-questions) and am disappointed, it would have been appropriate here. Thanks for all anyway.

Answer (score 16):

More often than not, when someone posts a bounty and lets it run its course they are looking for the question to get additional attention and hopefully *new* answers.

Auto-awarding is only a last recourse in case the bounty poster doesn't award the bounty manually.

Awarding this "consolation" prize to existing questions would, in most cases, conflict with the bounty poster intentions even more than at least awarding it to an answer posted in response to the bounty.

Comment: I'm not thrilled on you changing the question so fundamentally after it was answered. But my post still should answer your edited question.

Comment: I admit I've had the feeling it was disrupting your answer a bit, yes :-/ Should I switch it back?

Comment: Leave it be now, the answer still works after I removed the first paragraph. But changing questions in ways that invalidate existing answers is a no-no normally. Don't do that.

Comment: Clarifying the question is a yes yes @RomainValeri, it makes the information provided in answers easier to find. Please don't give bogus advice yivi. There's nothing on the site that prevents people from improving their post, even after answers were provided. Otherwise, closed questions with answers would never be fixed.

Comment: @Romain Whatever other users say, changing questions to invalidate existing answers is not welcome, and is usually rolled back. Read on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286803/change-to-question-invalidates-my-answer-what-to-do) for more information, there are plenty Q&A's to that effect. But this is getting off-topic from the question asked. I'm out.

Comment: Don't know if it needs to be precised, but looks natural that placing a bounty to get _new answers_ means that existing ones are considered not satisfying by the one who places it